# how do I set the PATH on Mac permanently (specifically for subversion upgrade)

Tags: svn, macos, path

Grrr, getting an error in RadRails that I need to upgrade suversion when I try to run script/plugin install.  So I followed the instructions to download the .dmg for 1.6.6.

I have tried to save the PATH for /opt/subversion/bin by editing ~/.profile, and even editing the etc/profile file.  No avail.

It still comes up svn --version as 1.4.6.

When I edit .bash_profile and then run . .bash_profile, in that terminal, it has 1.6.6 so I know that it is possible.

But when I go back to my RadRails or open another terminal, svn --version still points to the same, and echo $PATH no longer includes the /opt/subversiion/bin directory.

How can I make sure that directory is included first from now on?

Per the comments below:

```
which svn

/opt/subversion/bin/svn


echo $PATH

/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/subversion/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin
```

Comment: Could you add the exact line you have in `~/.bash_profile`, as well as what `echo $PATH` currently says? Also, what does `which svn` tell you?

Comment: hiya!  yep added the echo $PATH and which svn...oddly, ~/.bash_profile is now empty.....odd.....

Comment: sigh...I *thought* I got it but I did a svn --version from the command line in RadRails and...STILL...I actually deleted anything with SVN in the usr/local/bin directory....

Comment: aha!  command line in RadRails (Eclipse) which svn gives me usr/local/bin and from terminal I get the *correct* opt/subversion/bin....wut's up with that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never found the exact answer, but RadRails terminal wasn't a true terminal and so that created problem.s

Answer (score 1):

See [here](http://www.astro.washington.edu/users/rowen/AquaEnvVar.html) (link found by googling for the filename).

Though, I’ve not used RadRails, but I would expect that it should allow you to configure the path to svn itself.